# Preview or Create sample PDF with PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I have searched and can't seem to find anything that provides a solution to this. What I'm trying to do is there are files uploaded onto the server and I'm trying to create a preview facility similar to that of amazon and only show a few pages of the pdf.

I have managed to do this with MP3s with php but I'm really struggling for PDFs. The idea would be that it would cut the pdf and only show the first 2 pages in a pdf sample.

I have tried using substr to limit the output on saving the php but this doesn't work.

Does anyone else know how to solve this issue?

Comment: A google search on `php parse pdf` will probably get you started. As it is now, your question seems too broad to get an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) with [fpdi](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/):

```
<?php

include 'fpdf/fpdf.php';
include 'fpdi/fpdi.php';

$pdf = new FPDI();
// add a page
// set the source file
$pdf->setSourceFile("document.pdf");

// import page 1 
// you can repeat this or put inside a loop 
// to import multiple pages by their page number
$pdf->AddPage();
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);

$pdf->Output();
```

Note that this won't work with encrypted files.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks so much for your help. For others using the following code can be used to save the file after processing...

Comment: $filename="/home/user/public_html/test.pdf";
$pdf->Output($filename,'F');